# Curved waved lines with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, feynman

I'm trying to write a code for Feynman diagrams with TikZ (I know it is a common subject in the forum). I found very useful posts. However, I would like to draw a curved waved line

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \path [draw=blue]
    (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (2,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw[draw=blue,snake=coil, segment aspect=0] (2,0) arc (0:180:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code just draw a solid line, no waved.

Can anyone help me solve this weird behaviour?

Comment: You aren't invoking the decorations.  A decoration needs to be defined (usually via the `decoration` key) **and** invoked, via the `decorate` key.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually the library `snakes` has been superseded by `decorations`, but for your need I think you are just looking for `decorations.pathmorphing`.

Thus, your code revised, is like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{snake it/.style={decorate, decoration=snake}}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \path [draw=blue,snake it]
    (-4,0) -- (-2,0) -- (2,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw[draw=blue, snake it] (2,0) arc (0:180:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I grouped in a single style `snake it` the keys that really set up the decoration `decorate` and the one that sets the type of decoration `decoration=snake`.

For further details, you can have a look to section **72 Decorations** and more specifically to section **30.2 Path Morphing Decorations** on the pgfmanual. (section **48.2** in pgfmanual 3.0)

Comment: Thank you @claudio, your answer was very helpful!! Cheers

Answer (score 13):

The new [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) package (see also the [project page](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman)) makes it easy to create Feynman diagrams.

The following is just an example to show its capabilities.  The relevant key to produce the half circle is `half left`.  You have to compile with `lualatex` in order to exploit the automatic positioning of vertices.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to d] {
  a -- [scalar,red] b -- [fermion,blue] c -- [gluon,orange] d,
  b -- [photon, half left] c, % this produces the curved photon line
};
\end{document}
```

> [image]