# Tikz, decorations

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, decorations, feynman

I use tikz as a general purpose drawing package because of its flexibility etc... I need to draw some Feynman diagrams like these:

[image: Feynman diagrams with vector loops]

I tried to draw arc like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [decorate, decoration={snake}] (0,0) arc (180:0:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the result is ugly looking:

[image: Ugly looking result with Tikz]

Googleing I found some interesting link:

[Other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88971/tikz-avoiding-line-segments-in-snake-path)

but

1) I tried to compile and the result was different:

[image: Link result]

2) As you can see in the first image I posted, I need arbitrary angle arc and, in the solution presented in the link, it seems possible to draw only semicircles

3) The code is not elegant at all: in particular, using this solution drawing a solid e arc or a snakeish arc requires complete different source code.

I was thinking if it is possible simply to stop the arc when it reaches the specified (final) angle, without any regard to the decoration.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/nicer-wavy-line-with-tikz/25689#25689 and this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29639/tikz-finishes-a-morphed-path-with-a-straight-segment

Comment: It is not a duplicate because:
1) The solution given in the link you posted tried to reproduce only the "snake" decoration (for other decoration it would be more complicate)
2) It doesn't work if you try to draw an arc.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88949/curved-waved-lines-with-tikz help?

Comment: I read that post, but unfortunately, the result is not good looking

Comment: Could you clarify the "not good looking" means to you?  The images you posted look fine to me, but then maybe I'm not seeing what you see.

Comment: I did some testing and TeX arithmetic is not precise enough to get the right number of cycles so it goes awry no matter what I've tried

Comment: The first image I posted IS good looking but IS NOT obtained by Tikz. How can I get similar results using Tikz

Comment: Are you aware that, using the `snake` transformation, you can set the amplitude and wavelength with the `amplitude` and `segment length` properties? I would think that setting the wavelength so that it divides the length of the path, the result would suit your needs.

Comment: I've already tried, but the final segment remains even if i set post length=0mm... Is it a bug?

Comment: Have you tried with `pre=curveto` and `pre length` and `post length` keys? They should mitigate such bad effect.

Comment: Hi @MaPo, you can ask your technical theoretical physics questions [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/32664/problem-with-ope-from-polchinski) if you want to, where they will neither wrongly get tagged nor closed as homework. Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the three Feynman diagrams shown in the question can be realized with a few lines of code using the new [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) package (see also the [project page](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman)).

Here is the code to produce all of them.  You must compile with `lualatex` in order to take advantage of the automatic positioning of the vertices.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\begin{document}
% first diagram
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to d] {
  a [particle=\(\mu\)] -- [photon] b [dot],
  b -- [anti fermion, half left, edge label=\(k\)] c [dot] --
  [half left, fermion, edge label=\(k + q\)] b,
  c -- [photon] d [particle=\(\nu\)],
};

% second diagram
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=a to d] {
  a -- b [dot] -- [fermion,edge label'=\(p + k\)] c [dot] -- d [particle=\(p\)],
  b -- [photon, half left, edge label=\(k\)] c,
};

% third diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a) {\(\mu\)};
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \vertex [above right=of b] (u1);
    \vertex [above right=of u1] (u2) {\(p'\)};
    \vertex [below right=of b] (d1);
    \vertex [below right=of d1] (d2) {\(p\)};

    \diagram*{
      (a) -- [photon, edge label'=\(q\)] (b),
      (b) -- [fermion, edge label=\(k+q\)] (u1) -- [fermion] (u2),
      (b) -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(k\)] (d1) -- [anti fermion] (d2),
      (d1) -- [photon, half right, edge label'=\(p - k\)] (u1),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun, with [`feynmp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmf) and egreg's [`feynmp-auto`](http://ctan.org/pkg/feynmp-auto). If on MikTeX or TeX Live 2012 or earlier, compile with `--shell-escape` (or `--enable-write18`) as command-line options. All manual positioning (`\fmfforce` commands) is done to match your sample, but the positions can be computed automatically by leaving these out.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\unitlength = 2mm
\begin{fmffile}{testing}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(30,20)
  \fmfleft{i} \fmfright{o}
  \fmflabel{$p$}{o}
  \fmf{plain}{i,v1} \fmf{plain}{v2,o}
  \fmf{fermion,label=$p+k$}{v1,v2}
  \fmf{photon,left,label=$k$}{v1,v2}
  \fmfdot{v1,v2}
  \fmfforce{(0.3w,0.5h)}{v1}
  \fmfforce{(0.6w,0.5h)}{v2}
  \fmfforce{(0.9w,0.5h)}{o}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` that avoids the need of `\DeclareGraphicsRule` and of redefining `\endfmffile`? `;-)` By the way, since the release of TeX Live 2013, `-shell-escape` is not needed for running `mpost`.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for that! I did not know about your `feynmp-auto` until now.

Comment: My hope was to learn ONE package that would allow me to get every diagram (Feynman and not Feynman) I wanted. Tikz seemed to me a package like the one I wanted. But evidently it is not...
The think that astonish me more is that even `\draw[decorate, decoration={snake, segment legth=5mm, post length=0mm}] (0,0) -- (0,2);` does not produce the intuitive result (at the end of the wavy line there is a straight segment... this let me think that, _at least_ decorations library is a bit buggy)

Comment: @MaPo well, this is `metapost`, so you could learn it and do all your other figures with `metapost`. Alternatively, Feynman diagrams can be done with `pstricks` or `asymptote` (both shown [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116083/how-to-plot-feynman-diagrams-with-pstricks)), which can also be used for more general figures/diagrams. And it is certainly possible with `tikz` as well. Each package has its advantages and disadvantages for different graphics needs.

Comment: @Paul Gessler: I knew, as a matter of facts, I asked how to get good-looking (or if you prefer not-ugly-looking) Feynman graph with Tikz, and I've no received any answer yet...

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with `tikz`, as requested. The problem with the linked answer is that the arguments to the `atan` function in the `pgf` low-level layer have been reversed. Switching the arguments inside the `wavy semicircle` definition solves that issue.

Code for the styles borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160358/21344).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160358/21344; changed photon style
\tikzset{
  fermion/.style={draw=black, postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow{Latex}}}},
  vertex/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=black,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt},
  photon/.style={wavy semicircle,wave amplitude=0.3mm,wave count=10}
}

% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89003/21344; swapped atan args
\newif\ifmirrorsemicircle
\tikzset{
    wave amplitude/.initial=0.2cm,
    wave count/.initial=8,
    mirror semicircle/.is if=mirrorsemicircle,
    mirror semicircle=false,
    wavy semicircle/.style={
        to path={
            let \p1 = (\tikztostart),
            \p2 = (\tikztotarget),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},
            \n2 = {atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1))} in
            plot [
                smooth,
                samples=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave count}+0.5)*8+1, % Calculate the number of samples needed, so the samples are in sync with the wave and fall on the extrema
                domain=0:1,
                shift={($(\p1)!0.5!(\p2)$)}
            ] ({ % Polar coordinates: Angle...
                (\x*180-\n2 + 180 + \ifmirrorsemicircle 1 \else -1 \fi * 90%
            }:{ % ... and radius
                (%
                    \n1/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave amplitude} * %
                    sin(
                        \x * 360 * (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave count} + 0.5%
                    )%
                )%
            })
        } (\tikztotarget)
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (i);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of i] (v1);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of v1] (v2);
\coordinate[right=of v2] (o);
\draw (i) -- (v1);
\draw[fermion] (v1) -- (v2) node[midway,below] {$p+k$};
\draw[photon] (v1) to (v2);
\path (v1) to[in=90,out=90] node[above=2mm]{$k$} (v2); % ghost path for label
\draw (v2) -- (o) node[right] {$p$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, I feel that `feynmp` is *much* better suited for these uses. Knowing how to use a hammer really well doesn't make it a good tool for sawing.

Comment: Thank you, for your patience. I totally agree with you:  `feynmp` _is much better suited for Feynman graph_